# Infix to postfix evaluation

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion

How do I convert char to Integer type?

```
int p2 = (int)stack2.pop();     
int p1 = (int)stack2.pop();       
int res = result(p2, p1, calStr.charAt(i));   

stack2.push(res);
```

I did the above method, but getting a `runtime error` that `java.lang.Character` cannot be cast to `java.lang.Integer`

> Exception in thread `"main"` `java.lang.ClassCastException:`
>   `java.lang.Character` cannot be cast to `java.lang.Integer`

Comment: Is `stack2` really `Stack<Character>`? If yes, why?

Comment: Why would you want to convert `char` to `int` here? Are you trying to ask how to convert a single **digit** (e.g. `'2'`) into a number (e.g. `2`), then use [`Character.digit(ch, 10)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit-char-int-), but do you truly only support single-digit numbers in your expression evaluator? Shouldn't the value on the stack already *be* a number?

Comment: I used stack2 as Integer stack.  I have used a string to read user's infix expression and the postfix expression is also in the form of string. But when I try to typecast the char at specific index as Int it gives me runtime error

Comment: So it's `calStr.charAt(i)` that's failing, then?

Comment: no the error was showing at      int p2 =(int)stack2.pop();      
  int p1= (int)stack2.pop();   I was getting the result in ASCII number.( p1,p2 were storing ASCII number of stack2.pop(). I used int n= p2 - '0';

Comment: What **signature** has the *result*-method?

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

You can not directly cast a `Character` to an `Integer`, those are **objects**. The cast between them only works if we are talking about the **datatypes** `char` and `int`.

While Java indeed *auto-boxes* and *-unboxes* `Integer` to `int`, `Character` to `char` and vice versa, it does not automatically use this technique for a fast conversion between `Integer` to `Character`.

---

### Solution

Of course you can do a transformation like:

```
Character -> char -> int -> Integer
```

So as code this could look like:

```
Character itemAsCharacter = stack2.pop();
char itemAsChar = itemAsCharacter.charValue();
int itemAsInt = (int) itemAsChar;
Integer itemAsInteger = Integer.valueOf(itemAsInt);
```

Or in short:

```
// Last step uses the implicit auto-boxing of int -> Integer
Integer item = (int) stack2.pop().charValue();
```

---

The backwards direction works similar:

```
Integer resultAsInt = ...
Character result = (char) resultAsInt.intValue();

stack2.push(result);
```

---

### Note

Please note that the class `Stack`, also `Vector`, are outdated classes in Java. There are classes with the same functionality that provide more methods, are more robust and simply more up-to-date. Examples for *LIFO* data-structures are listed under the interface `Deque`, the most common used implementation is `LinkedList` and there is also an array-variant, the `ArrayDeque`.

Here is the relevant excerpt from the [documentation of Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html):

> A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is
>   provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should
>   be used in preference to this class.